# How might I answer this past exam question relating to the limiting price of an option?

Tags: options, black-scholes

The following image shows a past exam question that I am attempting to answer (for which I do not have a mark scheme):

[image: question]

I *believe* that under the BMS model, the payoff of a stock at maturity $T$ is given by
$$
S_T = S_0 \exp \left( \mu T + \sigma W_T \right)
$$

Thus, the payoff of the stock in the question would be given by
$$
S_T = \exp \left( T + W_T \right)
$$

Therefore, I would expect the payoff of the option to be
$$
V_0 (T) = \left| \frac{T}{2} + T + W_T \right| = \left| \frac{3T}{2} + W_T \right|
$$

However,
$$
\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left| \frac{3T}{2} + W_T \right|}{\sqrt{T}} = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{3\sqrt{T}}{2} + \frac{W_T}{\sqrt{T}} \right| = \infty
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to avoid images and copy/paste instead. Also, if this is homework, then please use the homework tag.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can confirm that this is not homework, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- The price of the option is the expectation under the **risk-neutral measure**. Under this measure, the stock price's drift is $r$ and not $\mu$:
  $$dS_t = S_t r dt + S_t \sigma dW_t$$
- When you integrate to get $S_T$, you have made a mistake:
  $$S_T = S_0\exp\left(\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)T + \sigma W_T \right)$$

Start by writing out the expression of $d\ln(S_t)$ using **Itô's lemma**, then deduce $\ln(S_T)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, using your $S_T$ the limit simplifies to $\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \left| r \sqrt{T} + \frac{W_T}{\sqrt{T}} \right|$, which still tends to infinity?

Comment: $r = 0$ in your exam.

Comment: Of course it is, silly me.

Comment: Presumably this means that the fact that the drift $\mu = 1$ is provided is just to throw us off slightly?

Comment: Maybe to check whether the students understand that they shouldn't care about the real world drift when pricing the option.

Comment: So what's $c$ then? I was under the impression that $\frac{W_T}{T}$ doesn't converge ($\limsup = + \infty$ and $\liminf = -\infty$).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe that $\left| \frac{W_T}{\sqrt{T}} \right| = \frac{\sqrt{T}}{\sqrt{T}}$, since $W_T^2 = T$. So $c=1$.

Comment: $W_T ^2 = T$ is false, the brownian motion is a random process! You got it mixed up with $Var(W_T) = T$.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea. If I work it out I'll comment to let you know.